# How do I disable the "Syncing iPod. Do not disconnect." warning in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod

When syncing my iPod to iTunes, I always get this message:

[image: Syncing iPod. Do not disconnect]

I've had my iPod for several years now and I'd like to disable that warning, so I can see what's copying, how long it will take, etc., since I already know that I'm not supposed to disconnect my iPad. I know that I can click the little triangle on the left side to see the progress, but I don't want to have to do that. Is there a way to disable that warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with this issue is that that bar's display changes between "do not disconnect" message and the status of sync info. So it's not that static info saying "do not disconnect" all the time.

Anyway. There is no such tweak for disabling that message there since it's mandatory.

Cheers, C@N.

Comment: Correct, but I'd just like the static copying info, not the "Do not disconnect" message.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is no such tweak. :(

Comment: Too bad.... :-(